Class added by javascript but css not applied?
I am going to create a toggle menu using javascript and css
A class .menu-slider add with property display blok. But it's not working only class teggled and css not applied
Here is the code
<script>
    const toggleMenu = document.querySelector('.toggl-menu');
    document.getElementById("toggleButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var button = this;
        toggleMenu.classList.toggle('menu-slider');
        button.classList.toggle("open");
        button.classList.toggle("close");
        var openIcon = button.querySelector(".open-icon");
        var closeIcon = button.querySelector(".close-icon");
        if (button.classList.contains("open")) {
            openIcon.style.display = "inline";
            closeIcon.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            openIcon.style.display = "none";
            closeIcon.style.display = "inline";
        }
    });
</script>

<style>
    .toggl-menu {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding-top: 1rem;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        align-items: center;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        left: 0;    
        top: 70px;
    }
    .menu-slier{
        display: block;
        transition-duration: 500ms;
    }
</style>


soley caused by typos. For ocne your CSS class is menu-slier while in JS you toggle menu-slider

Use your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what css is being applied and from where and also to check there are no errors shown on the console.

Perhaps the fact is that in your JS you are toggle the menu-slider class, but in css you have .menu-slier

no it's not working both classes i have applied but nothin happen

you should never answer on questions tha are soelyl cause by typos but comment don't hem instead and flag them as such for closure!
